# Why am I getting connect time out error from AWS SES when the limit has been increased?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-ses

I had my web app running in EC2 instance(AWS server 1). I have another AWS server 2 where the DB is. I had a verified domain and verified recipient test email address and emails were going out well. One day I did Elastic IP so that AWS 1 talk to AWS 2 for some other purpose. Not sure if that caused the issue. Now I reverted AWS 1 to normal Ipv4 address(removed Elastic IP) and all over my app and for SSH I use normal IPv4 address.

1. As per other posts, I also contacted AWS and increased the sending
   limit.
2. I also set the outbound rules SMTP and SMTPS. None seems to
       be working.
3. If I run the web app in my localhost with same SES
       credentials, emails are sent out. Only when my web app is in Amazon EC2 then emails are not being sent out.

Following is the error that I am getting.

```
Unable to execute HTTP request: Connect to email.us-west-2.amazonaws.com:443 [email.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/52.94.209.0] failed: connect timed out
```

It's been 2 days and I am scratching my head to get it resolved. Please help.

PS: As per request, here are the outbound rules

Type : MYSQL/Aurora
Protocol: TCP
Port Range: 3306
Destination : //MyIP

I don't have any other outbound rule.

Comment: sounds like a firewall issue. Can you please update the question with the security group outbound rules and Network ACLs (if running within a VPC) ?

Comment: @gsaslis Done. I see a VPC for my instance, but I don't what it means and what should I do with that?

Comment: Your outbound rules need to allow any/all unless you understand how to configure them more specifically.  Did you remove the default rule?

Comment: That isn't an SMTP request.  Note that the error indicates HTTP (or HTTPS), which is what the SDKs would be expected to use when talking to SES (not SMTP).  Note also that exceeding a limit would be expected to cause a specific error about the limit, not a timeout.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Stupid stackoverflow doesn't let me to update my comment within 5 minutes. After my previous comment, I went and removed all outgoing rules and it worked. By the way, if I have an outbound rule for MySQL protocol set, won't the other protocols' rules be default (As set by AWS)??